# PLSQL (finding range of prime number to 1000 )

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    n NUMBER;<br>i NUMBER;
    pr NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR n IN 2 .. 1000 LOOP
            pr := 1;
            FOR i IN 2 .. n / 2 LOOP
                    IF MOD(n, i) = 0 THEN
                        pr := 0;
                    END IF;
            END LOOP;
            IF (N = 997) THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(n);
                pr:=2;
            ELSE
                IF pr = 1 THEN         
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(n||'&');
                END IF;
            END if;
        END LOOP;
        dbms_output.new_line;
END;
```

output should be as in one line---->

```
2&3&5&7&11&13&17&19&23&29&31&37&41&43&47&53&59&61&67&71&73&79&83&89&97&101&103&107&109&113&127&131&137&139&149&151&157&163&167&173&179&181&191&193&197&199&211&223&227&229&233&239&241&251&257&263&269&271&277&281&283&293&307&311&313&317&331&337&347&349&353&359&367&373&379&383&389&397&401&409&419&421&431&433&439&443&449&457&461&463&467&479&487&491&499&503&509&521&523&541&547&557&563&569&571&577&587&593&599&601&607&613&617&619&631&641&643&647&653&659&661&673&677&683&691&701&709&719&727&733&739&743&751&757&761&769&773&787&797&809&811&821&823&827&829&839&853&857&859&863&877&881&883&887&907&911&919&929&937&941&947&953&967&971&977&983&991&997
```

but not working in hackerrank compiler question is "Print Prime Numbers"

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Just remove `<br>i NUMBER;`, then it produces the string as you want , but tag `mysql` should be replaced with `oracle`.

Comment: the <br> tag i used to give line space in placing my code it does not lie at all in the actual code

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in your code to produce the desired string *except* `<br>i NUMBER;`

Just comment out that piece in the declaration section as below :

```
DECLARE
    n NUMBER; -- <br>i NUMBER;
    pr NUMBER;
```

Here's a [Demo](http://rextester.com/UIX31562) for it.

Comment: the <br> tag i used to give line space in placing my code it does not lie at all in the actual code

Comment: @Akashkesarwani I've just added a demo.